# Check if a ray has hit a corner

Tags: geometry, algorithms

I'm trying to find an algorithm to detect if a ray (line) is intersecting a corner can pass by it or is blocked.

On [this paper](https://legends2k.github.io/2d-fov/design.html#vision-beyond-corners), it states that the separating axis theorem can be applied to find it could, but after reading it I'm still very confused on how it can be done.

[image: Example]

The examples with orange lines show how a line could go past a corner, and the first picture illustrates how the ray wouldn't be able to.